# How to Mock a Java Object in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, mocking

I'm exploring `clojure.contrib.mock`. I think I learned how to mock Clojure functions, but I don't see anything about mocking Java objects.

Is there a Clojure library to help me create Java mock objects or will I have to bring in libraries like EasyMock?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the Java objects you're trying to mock, you may find `proxy` and/or `reify` useful since they let you create Java-compatible objects in Clojure. Can you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?